# What kind of adverb is the word "most"?

Tags: adverbs, parts-of-speech

I am analyzing a sentence where I have this phrase: They are the ones most affected.
"Most" here is an adverb, isn't? So, what kind of adverb is it?

Comment: What do you mean "what kind of adverb"?  What kinds of adverbs do you think there are?

Comment: https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/most_1

Answer (score 1):

I think ,by 'kind of adverb', you bear in mind the adverbs of time, place, manner, frequency, cause, degree, etc. So, in the phrase 'most affected', obviously, the word *most* modifies the adjective *affected*, and answers 'How much?' An *Adverb of Degree* shows the intensity of an adjective, adverb or a verb. Hence, it is an *adverb of degree*.

Answer (score 0):

The word "most" here modifies the verb "affected" so it is indeed an adverb in this usage. To the best of my understanding there are not really separate "kinds" of adverbs.